# Validation Rule. Change ownership only if the user is the owner or the owner is "x" user

Tags: validation-rule, ownership

I created a Validation Rule to prevent a user to change the record's ownership when is not the owner:

$User.Id <> PriorValue(OwnerId) && ISCHANGED( OwnerId )
It worked.

But I also need any let any user update the ownership in case the current owner is a specific user (user id = '2F0055e000000gdKL').

I tried several ways, but nothing worked.
Then I tried to focus only on the specific user validation. It didn't work either:

PriorValue(OwnerId) <> '2F0055e000000gdKL'
&&
ISCHANGED( OwnerId )

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This validation rule did not work because `2F0055e000000gdKL` is not a valid User Id.

Presumably the value you've got came from a URL that was encoded as `%2F0055e000000gdKL` and you kept part of the `%2F` from the encoded slash character.

The valid user id starts with `005`

`0055e000000gdKL`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I updated it, but it's not working either. I'm lost here, I tried several ways, but it seems that I'm unable to use User.id in this Validation Rule...